# Convert month number to month name from array in JS

Tags: javascript

I receive data from Ajax in the form of the number of the month

```
0: 2018 - year
1: 6 - month
2: 7 - day
```

How I can convert it to month name?
Example:

```
0: 2018 - year
1: "Jun" - month
2: 7 - day
```

Comment: An array filled with the values at the corresponding indices

Comment: [moment](https://momentjs.com/) is great for dealing with time and dates.  If you don't want an outside library, just create your own object mapping month numbers to their names and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here:

```js
function monthName(mon) {
   return ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'][mon - 1];
}

console.log(monthName(7));
```

When you're ready for a more professional solution, use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: In OP's example "6" is "June".

Comment: Can I suggest you edit the index in your answer to match the OP's numbering system?

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, your array is missing October

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March",  "April", "May", "June",  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const d = new Date();
document.write("The current month is " + 
monthNames[d.getMonth()]);
```

Or try

```
var date = new Date("10/11/2018"),
locale = "en-us",
month = date.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = {
 0: 2018,
 1: 6,
 2: 7
}
let months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'November', 'December']
```

If you you always have month at index 1 in the data Object from response, you can directly set it to the defined month name.

```
data[1] = months[data[1]-1];
```

This will be the output

```
{ 
  0: 2018, 
  1: 'June', 
  2: 7 
}
```